# Why a constant pointer of type character as a function?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and I've came across this and I don't understand this small thing. Why is the GetName() function a pointer of type character and why is it constant?

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int nValue)
        : Base(nValue)
    {
    }

    const char* GetName() { return "Derived"; }
    int GetValueDoubled() { return m_nValue * 2; }
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"Derived"` is a **string literal** (look it up). If you attempt to modify a string literal, you get undefined behaviour, so the return type is marked `const` so you don't accidentally modify it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a [C-String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string). It is a pointer to the first element of an array of `chars`, and is `const` because you shouldn't edit a character literal.

Answer (score 0):

Remember in C++ you cannot return a bunch of values from a function. As they said, this returns a pointer to where a group of sequential characters ares saved. A pointer is a reference to an address in memory.
When you write a getValue method in class most of the time you only want to let know whoever is outside what the value is, but just as read only, because you as the class are the only owner of that value and if the value gets changed from a random place and not from a setValue method it can cause problems.